# 30GB EBS Backed Ubuntu server showing 7.74GB in landscape-sysinfo

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I created a ec2 instance with 30GB of EBS volumne. However when i SSH into my ec2 instance, the landscape-sysinfo says usage of 9.7% of 7.74GB. 
Wasn't it suppose to be 30GB instead of 7.74GB

System information as of Mon Dec 15 09:14:29 UTC 2014

```
System load: 0.4              Memory usage: 1%   Processes:       89
Usage of /:  9.7% of 7.74GB   Swap usage:   0%   Users logged in: 0
```

Thanks I'm sure I'm missing something here because the volumes show that it is of 30GB

EDIT:
It showed the correct value after 10-15mins

Answer (score 0):

More than likely your disks are not yet correctly attached to your instance.
When you add additional disk space to an EC2 instance, your disk isn't immediately mounted on your Linux.

ITKBCentral has a [blog post](http://itkbcentral.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/how-to-increase-disk-space-on-existing.html) with a tutorial on how to move your running instance to a larger disk.
If this isn't your current situation, please provide more information about your EC2 volumes and maybe the output of parted / fdisk -l commands on your linux distro.